# Vector Magnetic Potential and pointwise current density source

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, vector-fields, dipole

I am currently studying antennas and I am trying to understand how to solve the following vector equation $$\nabla^2A+k^2A=-\mu J$$ in the case when there is a point current source at the origin.

The notes I'm following proceed to define the current density as:
$$J = \delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)\hat{a}$$ which I totally agree it only exists at the origin, but my question is: what is the unit measure of that particular current density? To me it looks to be $[m^{-3}]$, which is not a current density. Is this legitimate in any case? Are there other approaches in solving the case of a pointwise current source?

The notes also try to solve the case for which the current density is infinitly thin along the $\hat{z}$ axis (Hertzian dipole), and it uses:
$$J = I_o\delta(x)\delta(y)f(z)$$
In this case the units seem to be ok, since [A][$m^{-1}$][$m^{-1}$] indeed is a current density, if we agree on saying that the unit measure of $\delta(\cdot)$ is $ [m^{-1}]$.

I really appreciate any suggestion and thank you for taking the time to read this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The notes I'm following proceed to define the current density as:
> $$\mathbf{J}=\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)\hat{\mathbf{a}}$$
> which I totally agree it only exists at the origin, but my question is:
> what is the unit measure of that particular current density?
> To me it looks to be [$m^{−3}$],
> which is not a current density. Is this legitimate in any case?

You are right. Since $\mathbf{J}$ has unit $\text{Am}^{-2}$ and
$\hat{\mathbf{a}}$ (being a unit-vector) is supposed to be unit-less,
a factor $C$ with unit $\text{Am}$ is missing.
So let us insert this factor.
$$\mathbf{J}=\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)C\hat{\mathbf{a}}$$

Then a solution of
$$\nabla^2\mathbf{A}+k^2\mathbf{A}=-\mu \mathbf{J}$$
would be
$$\mathbf{A}=\mu C\hat{\mathbf{a}}\frac{e^{ikr}}{4\pi r}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I still have a doubt. Suppose I wanted to build a current density distribution that was made of many pointwise elements. Then I think I would need to weight the initial expression of J (the one with the three deltas) by a term, let's call it Jn, that is the current density of that point, like J = JnD(x)D(y)D(z). Then again the units don't match, as [Am^(-2)][m^(-3)]. Would I still need to have an extra C term to fix the units, and for example make C = 1 m^3 ? I don't know why this seems so strange to me, the notes seem to not care about this. Thank you.

Comment: @edoverg I'm not sure I understand your doubt. For a general current density $\mathbf{J}$ you need to weigh in the contributions from every point. You will get an integral similar to  
[Magnetic vector potential - Calculation of potentials from source distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential#Calculation_of_potentials_from_source_distributions).